# Modx manager: lang.js.php returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: apache, modx, http-status-code-401, modx-revolution

I moved my ModX website from localhost to a development server.

I updated the paths in my config files it seems to be doing fine, the frontend is working properly.

Only issue, when trying to load the manager at http://dev.noculture.asia/manager/, there is a request to connectors/lang.js.php: http://dev.noculture.asia/connectors/lang.js.php?ctx=mgr&topic=topmenu,file,resource,welcome,configcheck&action=

This request returns a 401 Unauthorized error and I have no idea why.

[image]

The logs aren't helpful at all:

Modx doesn't log any error, so I am guessing that means the error comes from Apache.

Apache error.log is empty, access.log only tells:

```
[11/Feb/2014:21:41:10 -0800] "GET /connectors/lang.js.php?ctx=mgr&topic=topmenu,file,resource,welcome,configcheck&action= HTTP/1.1" 401 391 "http://dev.noculture.asia/manager/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.102 Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Might be more information in your web server's error log about the 401

Comment: I had hit this issue, I ended up having to reinstall modx again, well run the upgrade script, and then it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that a 401 error is related to authentication.

I deleted the cookie for this domain, which destroyed my session. I was asked to login again, and now the manager is working properly.